# How can I redirect to different views on authorization failure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

While using mvc intranet template with domain authorization, how can I redirect to some certain error page on authorization failure depending on the controller?

So, I have a controller class:

```
    [AuthorizeWithRedirect(Users = @"user")]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
    ...
    }
```

By default I'm not redirected anywhere. I see only a blank page, if I open the page under another user. The issue is that I want the request to be redirected to different pages for different controllers if the authorization fails. That is, one page for `MyController`, another page for other controller, etc.

I know I could derive from `AuthorizeAttribute` and override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method. But I can't make it work:

```
public class AuthorizeWithRedirect : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
   {
       UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);
       context.Result = new RedirectResult(urlHelper.Action("MyErrorPage"));
   }
}
```

I get an error, saying that the specified url is not found, while `MyErrorPage.cshtml` does present in the `Views\Shared` folder.

**EDIT**

```
    [Authorize(Users = @"user")]//should be redirected to ErrorPage1
    public class MyController1 : Controller
    {
    ...
    }
```

while

```
    [Authorize(Users = @"user")]//should be redirected to ErrorPage2
    public class MyController2 : Controller
    {
    ...
    }
```

That is, different error pages for different controllers on one and the same authorization failure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AuthorizeWithRedirect  looks good.
But MVC is complaining that you do not have right action method.

The view is not an issue here. The controller and action method is.

Try something like this:

```
context.Result = new RedirectResult(urlHelper.Action("Test", "Redirect"));
```

With present TestController with an public action method Redirect.

Comment: The view I want to get redirected to is a shared one. It's in a `Shared` folder. So how can I redirect to it, could you, please, give a piece of advice?

Comment: Make a controller and action as I wrote and the action can then return the view in question. Technically this is not a redirect, but it maybe doesn't have to be. The desired view is sent to the browser. If you already have some similar controller and action you can use that in HandleUnauthorizedRequest.

Comment: urlHelper.Action always works with controllers and their methods, never directly with views.

Comment: It worked. At first, I tried to redirect to an action method from the same view, but it couldn't authorize....so an infinte loop occured))) Then I did the same in a separate view without any authorization restrictions, and it worker.

Comment: Could you please say, whether I could have a better approach for this kind of redirection issue? Not deriving from `Authorize`?

Answer (score -1):

Use the Handle Error Data Annotation on top of your login method

```
[HandleError]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    //your action method
}
```

Comment: sorry that's just a placeholder name. What i mean is the HandleError annotation will catch any exception your action method may throw and then redirect users to your specified/default error page